# Symfony 3.4:The service "nelmio_api_doc.formatter.html_formatter" has a dependency on a non-existent service "templating"

Tags: symfony, nelmioapidocbundle

This is the require section of the composer.json file from the Symfony 3.4 project

```
 "require": {
            "php": ">=5.5.9",
            "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
            "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
            "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.3",
            "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
            "jms/serializer-bundle": "^2.3",
            "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^2.12",
            "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
            "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.0.0",
            "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
            "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
            "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.6.4",
            "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
            "symfony/templating": "^4.0",
            "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
```

Comment: Basically a dup of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48598593/error-when-trying-to-install-sonata-admin-in-symfony-4/48599728#48599728

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this problem, install the template component using composer:

```
composer require symfony/templating
```

Then, add the following configuration under the framework key in config.yml:

```
templating:
    engines: ['twig']
```