# Dependency on a non-existent service "templating"

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I tried to use

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    project.controller.some:
        class: Project\SomeBundle\Controller\SomeController
        arguments: ['@templating']
```

and

```
namespace Project\SomeBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class SomeController
{
    private $templating;

    public function __construct(EngineInterface $templating)
    {
        $this->templating = $templating;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->templating->render(
            'SomeBundle::template.html.twig',
            array(

            )
        );
    }
}
```

in Symfony 4 flex. Now I get the error

```
ServiceNotFoundException

The service "project.controller.some" has a dependency on a non-existent service "templating".
```

Please tell me how to solve this. My composer.json already contains "symfony/templating": "^4.0" but this seems not to be enough.

Comment: Just one more little step: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48598593/error-when-trying-to-install-sonata-admin-in-symfony-4/48599728#48599728

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **Symfony 4** you can also use new DI features (already available since Symfony 3.3):

- [`_defaults`](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/07/how-to-refactor-to-new-dependency-injection-features-in-symfony-3-3/#1-let-s-add-code-defaults-code)
- [class named service](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/07/how-to-refactor-to-new-dependency-injection-features-in-symfony-3-3/#3-use-class-named-services)

They will simplify all to:

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowired: true

    Project\SomeBundle\Controller\SomeController: ~
```

If you want to know more with real before/after examples, read [How to refactor to new Dependency Injection features in Symfony 3.3](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/07/how-to-refactor-to-new-dependency-injection-features-in-symfony-3-3/)

Answer (score 3):

Symfony 4 doesn't include Twig by default, so you need to install it first:

```
composer require twig
```

should do the trick. Also, with service autowiring in Symfony 4 you don't need to manually declare it in the `services.yml`.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to add the configuration under `framework` as explained in the [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/3.1/templating/templating_service.html)

```
# app/config/packages/framework.yaml
framework:
    # ...
    templating: { engines: ['twig'] }
```